# VueJS how to make a button disabled, under different conditions?

Tags: vue.js

I have a button on my website that gives bonuses to the user. I need to make several conditions in 1 button.

If `heal_used = 1` or `diff < 1`, the button must be disabled. I tried to do it like this:

```
<button v-if="heal_used 1" :disabled="diff < 1" v-else class="btn btn--small btn--purple" @click="takeBonus">Take</button>
```

But nothing worked. Also, if the button is active and the user can get a bonus, after the bonus you need to make the button inactive. I did it like this:

```
if (data.type === 'success') {
          this.bonus_num = data.bonus_num;
          this.heal_used = data.heal_used;
          this.$forceUpdate();
        }
```

Is it true? Can you help me please, to make 2 condifitions?

**UPDATE**

I change code to:

```
<button class="btn btn--small btn--purple" :disabled="isDisabled" @click="takeBonus">Take</button>
```

And add:

```
computed: {
 isDisabled() {
  return this.heal_used = 1 || this.diff < 10;
},
```

},

Console.log say me:

```
console.log(data.heal_used);
console.log(data.diff);
0
17
```

But button is stil; disabled, what's wrong?

**UPDATE takeBonus:**

```
takeBonus() {
  this.$root.axios.post('/user/takeBonus', {
    value: this.user.cashback
  })
      .then(res => {
        const data = res.data;

        if (data.type === 'success') {
          this.bonus_num = data.bonus_num;
          this.$root.user.balance = data.newBalance;
          this.heal_used = data.heal_used;
          this.$forceUpdate();
        }

        this.$root.showNotify(data.type, this.$t(`index.${data.message}`));
      })
},
```

Comment: Should be `this.heal_used === 1`.  otherwise you're just setting it to 1 each time

Comment: yup, now it's work. but another, i add to computed: `this.$forceUpdate();`, and when i click to button, it's not disabled, after click

Comment: It's not clear what `takeBonus` does.  Does it communicate with a server?  What is `data.type`?  Too much hidden code.

Comment: yes, it's communicated with server, i update my question with code

Comment: You never need `forceUpdate`.  But aside from that, where does the function fail?  Test each variable in the console.

Comment: now `forceUpdate` update bonus number, which user can received in 1 day, all good, it's updated. But when user click to `Take` button, it's don't put button to disabled condition

Comment: `console.log(data.heal_used)` ?

Comment: `console.log(data.heal_used);` -> `0`; `console.log(data.diff);` -> 17

Comment: Then it won't be disabled.  It's disabled when `heal_used` is 1 or diff is less than 10.  This is how you wrote the condition in the computed

Comment: i understand, now i make `heal_used 0`, button in not disabled, i click to `Take` button, button still NOT disabled, when i update page, button is disabled. i need make disabled button when user Click on `Take`, i need render page in this situation

Comment: Your server needs to send back 1 instead of 0 for `heal_used`...

Comment: you can't understand me. when i click `Take`, console say me, that server SEND me 1, all good.

Comment: When I asked you what the `console.log` was, you said 0, now you say 1.  So of course I don't understand you :)  I'll let someone else try

Comment: if i truncate my database, and i go to page, `console.log` say me 0, than if i click `Take` button, `console.log` say me 1, without reload page. I hope I explained clearly :)

Comment: You're using `v-if` and `v-else` on the same component. I'd say that's the problem. You're supposed to use `v-if` on one element and `v-else` on the subsequent sibling. Optionally, you can have `v-if-else` siblings between them.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  new Vue({
    el: '#example',
    data: {
      heal_used : 4, 
      diff:  3
    },
    methods: {
      takeBonus1: function () {
        this.heal_used=1;
        this.diff=0;
      },
      takeBonus2: function () {
        this.heal_used=1;
        this.diff=4;
      },
      takeBonus3: function () {
        this.heal_used=2;
        this.diff=.1;
      },
      reset: function () {
        this.heal_used=4;
        this.diff=3;
      }
    }
  })
```

```html
<head>
  <title>My first Vue app</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="example">
    <p>
      <span>heal_used: {{ heal_used }}</span>
      <span>diff: {{ diff }}</span>
    </p>
    <button 
      @click="takeBonus1()" 
      :disabled="heal_used===1 || diff < 1" >
        Take bonus (both)
    </button>
    <br>
    <button 
      @click="takeBonus2()" 
      :disabled="heal_used===1 || diff < 1" >
        Take bonus (heal_used===1)
    </button>
    <br/>
    <button 
      @click="takeBonus3()" 
      :disabled="heal_used===1 || diff < 1" >
        Take bonus (diff < 1)
    </button>
    <br>  
    <button 
      @click="reset()"> 
        Reset
    </button>
  </div>
</body>
```